# Joi 'when/is' syntax - how to check for type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I'm using the Joi library to validate an object. I want to make a certain property required when another optional property (at the same level of the same object) is of a certain type, e.g. string. The Joi docs show this example:

```
const schema = {
    a: Joi.when('b', { is: true, then: Joi.required() }),
    b: Joi.boolean()
};
```

However, rather than checking that b (for instance) is true, I'd like to check whether it is a string. I've tried this:

```
const schema = {
    a: Joi.when('b', { is: Joi.string(), then: Joi.required() }),
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work. If I remove b completely from the object Joi still seems to expect a to be required. If b isn't in the object I don't want any validation placed on a.

I can't find any other examples of people doing this - can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

We managed to solve this using [object.with](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.2.0/API.md#objectwithkey-peers). If one key is present (e.g. a), then its peers must be present too (e.g. b).

However, it's not ideal because while we were able to specify that a should be a Joi.string(), object.with is looking for its mere presence rather than its type. So if a non-string a is present a 'should be a string' error will be thrown for a. It should be perfectly fine for a not to be a string - all that should mean is that b is not mandatory. I hope that makes sense.